# Jenkins JObDSL conditional build step send email issue

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am trying to write jobdsl block for conditional build step send email if the condition is true,
It fails for me, Please help improve the code below (stack trace below)

```
   job {
    name 'ci'
    description 'Build and test the app.'
    scm {
      git {
        remote {
          github 'sheehan/job-dsl-playground'
        }
      }
    }
   steps {
      gradle 'test'
       conditionalSteps {
         condition {
             stringsMatch('${ENV,var="CHILD_BUILD"}', "true", false)
         }
         extendedEmail("mthakkar@mycompany.com", "for Componets",
                      "Test Jira")  
    }
  }
        publishers {
          archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
      }
}
```

Stack Trace :

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.ConditionalStepsContext.extendedEmail()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String) values: [mthakkar@mycompany.com, for Componets, Test
>   Jira]     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.AbstractExtensibleContext.methodMissing(AbstractExtensibleContext.groovy:19)
>     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractContext.invokeMethod(AbstractContext.groovy)
>     at
>   script14321438737322039521488$_run_closure1_closure3_closure7.doCall(script14321438737322039521488.groovy:17)
>     at
>   script14321438737322039521488$_run_closure1_closure3_closure7.doCall(script14321438737322039521488.groovy)
>     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper.executeInContext(ContextHelper.groovy:14)
>     at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.conditionalSteps(StepContext.groovy:554)
>     at
>   script14321438737322039521488$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(script14321438737322039521488.groovy:13)  at
>   script14321438737322039521488$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(script14321438737322039521488.groovy)
>     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper.executeInContext(ContextHelper.groovy:14)
>     at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job.steps(Job.groovy:510)   at
>   script14321438737322039521488$_run_closure1.doCall(script14321438737322039521488.groovy:11)
>     at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.job(JobParent.groovy:110)     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.job(JobParent.groovy)  at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory$job.callCurrent(Unknown Source)   at
>   script14321438737322039521488.run(script14321438737322039521488.groovy:1)
>     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader.runDslEngineForParent(DslScriptLoader.java:72)
>     at
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader$runDslEngineForParent.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sheehan.jobdsl.DslScriptExecutor.execute(DslScriptExecutor.groovy:31)
>     at com.sheehan.jobdsl.ScriptExecutor$execute.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   Ratpack$_run_closure1_closure3_closure7.doCall(Ratpack.groovy:39)     at
>   ratpack.groovy.internal.ClosureInvoker.invoke(ClosureInvoker.java:65)
>     at
>   ratpack.groovy.handling.internal.ClosureBackedHandler.handle(ClosureBackedHandler.java:42)

Comment: Do you have the Conditional Step Plugin installed? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

Comment: yes , Also i think this is more of a config and is independent of the real plugin being installed or now

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at present the extended email step is a publisher

as per the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/31216b7487b28e3858e616b388f6d2314ffbce87/docs/Job-reference.md#extended-email-plugin)

> Publishers
>
> Block to contain list of publishers.
>
> Extended Email Plugin

```
 job {
     publishers {
         extendedEmail(String recipients = null, String subjectTemplate = null,
                       String contentTemplate = null) {
             trigger(String triggerName, String subject = null, String body = null,
                     String recipientList = null, Boolean sendToDevelopers = null,
                     Boolean sendToRequester = null, includeCulprits = null,
                     Boolean sendToRecipientList = null)
             trigger(Map args)
             configure(Closure configureClosure)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: yep but not in the conditional build step plugin , when i use the conditional build step plugin and add email the config.xml does not show it as publisher, but as a build step.  I also tired wrapping it around publisher just to check and that did not help :(

Comment: There is https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin which is the any build step to make publish steps into build steps. I don't think this is supported in job-dsl but you could craft it with configure blocks. It might be worth asking the job-dsl group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/Ot7BCx4lz8M I see you did ;)